# É certo escrever "el@" para designar "ele ou ela" e "lind@" para designar "lindo ou linda"?

Tags: gramática, ortografia

É uma linguagem que tenho visto na internet. Mas é gramaticalmente ou ortográficamente correto?

Muito possivelmente num contexto informal .

Comment: Esse é o tal gênero neutro. As gramáticas de hoje não falam sobre isso, pois é algo recentíssimo. É considerado linguagem informal, basicamente, mas é mais complexo e opinativo, então, este site não deve apresentar voz em relação ao gênero neutro, já que estamos aqui para informar e não para opinar, o que é impossível de não fazer com o gênero neutro.

Comment: eu tenho um amigo cego e ele usa aplicativos de leitura de tela para usar o computador e telefone... diz que atrapalha esse tipo de escrita.

Comment: Trata-se da proposta mais conhecida para utilização como linguagem de igualdade de género  n em relação à ortografia é o uso do sinal gráfico arroba (@) no lugar de -o, -a ou mesmo -e: "@s trabalhador@s" (pt), "l@s niñ@s" (es).

Answer (score 1):

Propostas para neutralidade na ortografia. linguagem para a igualdade de género.
Mas de acordo com a linguística, substituir masculino e feminino por um gênero neutro não funciona.

Leia mais em: https://www.gazetadopovo.com.br/educacao/elx-els-todxs-na-lingua-portuguesa-sem-genero-neutro-apenas-masculino-e-feminino-bm8jcy7i87jfe7geodpop4cbg/
Copyright © 2021, Gazeta do Povo. Todos os direitos reservados.

É a proposta mais conhecida para neutralidade de gêneros em relação à ortografia é o uso do sinal gráfico arroba (@) no lugar de -o, -a ou mesmo -e: "@s trabalhador@s" (pt), "l@s niñ@s" (es). Esse uso do [sinal] arroba é observado sobretudo entre os falantes de espanhol, apesar de condenado explicitamente pela Real Academia Espanhola,[14] que regula oficialmente a língua. No mundo lusófono, o uso do arroba como neutralizador de gênero é muito menos difundido; vem, no entanto, crescendo, como observado por exemplo em certas faculdades de ciências humanas de universidades brasileiras, como a Universidade de São Paulo (USP), a Universidade de Brasília (UnB) e a Universidade Estadual de Campinas (Unicamp).[15][16][17][18][19][20]

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_neutra_de_g%C3%AAneros_gramaticais

Answer (score 1):

Informalmente [visto](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de--para-marcar-o-genero-de-palavras/30218) na Internet, não faz parte da língua formal, mas faz um tempo que não vejo pessoas escrevendo com arrobas, este pode ser um jeito mais *antigo* ou *antiquado* da Internet de linguagem inclusiva.

Com o passar do tempo o arroba entrou na lista como uma proposta de linguagem neutra. Apesar de existirem várias [propostas de gênero neutro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_neutra_de_g%C3%AAneros_gramaticais), em [traduções nas plataformas de vídeos](https://revistaoeste.com/brasil/desenho-infantil-da-netflix-tem-personagens-que-falam-em-linguagem-neutra/) é comum ver o formato:

> Elu é linde

Isto pode ocorrer por conta do posicionamento da pessoa sobre assumir um [gênero não-binário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%AAnero_n%C3%A3o_bin%C3%A1rio). Também pode usar na questão inclusiva, que seria uma substituição para o @ (arroba).

Apesar da proposta também sugerir os arrobas, você cria um problema para pessoas que necessitam de leitores de texto. Irá quebrar a palavra em um som fora do comum: `lind arroba`. Faça o [teste](https://www.oratlas.com/leitor-de-texto-online) colocando as palavras da sua pergunta. Isto ocorre se utilizar a letra X (*xis*) também.

Outra forma gramaticalmente correta e inclusiva seria também usar [substantivos epicenos, sobrecomuns ou comum de dois gêneros](https://clubedoportugues.com.br/substantivos-epicenos-sobrecomum-e-comum-de-dois-o-que-e-isso/), este é mais comum do que a forma com arrobas, logo:

> Aquela pessoa é linda.

A pessoa é uma palavra que usa o gênero feminino, mas refere a alguém, não tem *o pessoo*.

Vale lembrar novamente que não quer dizer que o gênero da palavra, seja do adjetivo ou substantivo, sempre implica em referir a ele ou ela. Por isto o exemplo acima para usar pessoa.

A parte curiosa que o [latim já teve gênero neutro](http://www.filologia.org.br/rph/ANO21/63/002.pdf), por conta da evolução do idioma, boa parte dos gêneros neutros sumiram. Isto refletiu na língua portuguesa e em outros idiomas originados do latim.

Por fim, mesmo não sendo correto no contexto formal, de nada vale quão correto a definição se não transmite a mensagem apropriadamente ao seu público alvo.

Answer (score 0):

o uso de "@" aqui no Brasil é usado por algumas pessoas para deixar palavras neutras, mas isso dificulta totalmente a vida de pessoas que usam mecanismos de leituras, o correto deve ser usado "e" ou "u" para ajudar a leitura

Answer (score -1):

A língua portuguesa não possui um gênero neutro, apenas masculino e feminino. Há palavras que não têm gênero: preposições, alguns pronomes, verbos, advérbios, etc. Adjetivos, como linda/lindo, sempre têm gênero na língua portuguesa.

Comment: hellofriends, desculpa, mas essa resposta é uma opinião e nós trabalhamos com fatos no Portuguese StackExchange.

Comment: Perdão, acho que não aprendi nenhuma palavra com gênero neutro. Você pode me apresentar alguma obra do português com um adjetivo que não esteja no masculino ou no feminino?

Comment: hellofriends, existe “bonite” na linguagem informal. Mesmo que eu não use e ache desnecessário, existe na linguagem informal. Segundamente, isso não é uma opinião pelo gênero ser o que é, mas sim porque a tua resposta não tem referências ou um método, como checar cada palavra de vários dicionários de prestígio. Mesmo se checasses todas as palavras de vários dicionários de prestígio, apenas poderias concluir que ou não é boa prática ou não é comum. Resumindo, a tua resposta não possui premissas, fatos ou referências em geral.